# MouseOver with Cursor Pointer on Y Axis

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

The following implementation shows `mouseover` event with `cursor pointer` on y axis title label. It works and functional.

However, I want to implement `mouseover` event with `cursor pointer` on y axis (numeric axis) as well.

### [CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION](http://dojo.telerik.com/uxiGA)

Comment: It would be hard to do as numeric axis is composed of single "g" SVG elements. You could still implement showing "hand" pointer on values though.

Comment: actually I meant to add a hand pointer on y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the same color trick to the axis labels:

```
valueAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "N0",
        color: "rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)"
    },

$(document).on("mouseover", '#chart text[fill="rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)"]', function(){
    $('#chart text[fill="rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)"]').css("cursor", "pointer");
});
```

### Updated **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/avIDe)**

In this example I use the same color for title and labels, you could easily use a different color

Answer (score 1):

If you can add some id or class then it is good but in your code I cant find class so I used **stroke**

```
 $(document).on("mouseover", '#chart text[stroke="none"]', function(){
               $('#chart text[stroke="none"]').css("cursor", "pointer");
             });
```

Comment: Hi Keval it works but applies both x and y axis. I have upvoted your effort. You can add a class if it is neccessary on my code.

Comment: can you add id or class on it because in d3 we can  add id or class

Comment: Unfortunately KendoUI does not yet provide for applying classes to chart components.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a supported option with a custom visual:

```
categoryAxis: [{
labels: {
  color: "rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)",
  visual: function(e) {
    var visual = e.createVisual();
    visual.options.cursor = 'pointer';
    return visual;
  }
}
```

}]

[drawing.element.configuration.cursor](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing/element/configuration/cursor)

[Runnable Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iwiBiNUT)